# Clarification for StoryBoard references in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Recently I stumbled across a post discussing how property outlets should be referenced when set up from a storyboard. The post is question stated that when setting a reference from a storyboard, that is ctrl-dragging the reference into the associated header, that the reference should be set as weak, since the storyboard already has a strong reference to the property.

Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. It doesn't have anything to do with the storyboard having a reference. The outlets are usually set to weak, because they are references to UI elements that are subviews of some other view -- it's that view, the superview, that has the strong pointer (and ultimately, everything is a subview of the controller's self.view, and the controller has a strong pointer to it).